# Test of between groups difference in r-squared value in linear regression

Tags: regression, r-squared, group-differences

Running a linear regression with one continuous IV (sleep) and one categorical IV (gender). Have run a split-file analysis and there appears to be a difference between genders in r-squared. How would one test the significance of this difference (if possible)?

(Edit: Split-file is the process of considering the regression model for each group in the grouping variable separately i.e. in effect, males were first removed from analysis and DV was regressed on IV (sleep) and we get a slope and r-squared for females. The process is repeated with females removed, and we get a slope and r-squared for males. The slope is different between the groups, and we can see whether this difference is significant by the significance of the slope of the gender x sleep interaction. A difference or non-difference in slope doesn't indicate however whether there is a difference between men and women in the amount of variance in DV explained by sleep (r-squared). They could have a different slope but have the same amount of variance explained. The gender difference in r-squared is the one I am wondering how to test.)

Comment: What does split-file mean? If you regressed the response against gender and it is significant than the coefficient represents the partial slope of the model, that is the additive impact of gender 1 relative to gender 0.

Comment: @Robert Kubrick. Thanks very much for reply. Please see edit above for clarification of the process involved (split file) and the question of interest.